# Compute $(1+\alpha^4)(1+\alpha^3)(1+\alpha^2)(1+\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is the complex 5th root of unity with the smallest positive principal argument

Tags: complex-numbers

I just started on the topic Complex Numbers and there is a question that I am stuck on.

The question is:

> If $\alpha$ is a complex 5th root of unity with the smallest positive principal argument, determine the value of
>   $\mathbf(1+\alpha^4)(1+\alpha^3)(1+\alpha^2)(1+\alpha)$

From what I understand, I'm supposed to start with
a^5=1 and that the smallest positive argument should be 2π/5
To be exact, I got the roots $\mathbf{e^{\frac{2ki\pi}{5}}}$ in which k is from 0 to 4.
After that, I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: I can't read the question in the link.  Please type it using MathJax.

Comment: Please use informative titles.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the five $5^{th}$ roots of unity are $\,1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3,\alpha^4\,$. Also, if $\,\beta\,$ is a root of $\,z^5-1\,$ then $\,1+\beta\,$ is a root of $\,(z-1)^5-1\,$, and therefore $\,(1+1)(1+\alpha)(1+\alpha^2)(1+\alpha^3)(1+\alpha^4)\,$ is the product of the five roots of $\,(z-1)^5-1\,$.

Answer (score 2):

$$S=\mathbf(1+\alpha^4)(1+\alpha^3)(1+\alpha^2)(1+\alpha)$$
$$S(1-\alpha)=\mathbf(1+\alpha^4)(1+\alpha^3)(1+\alpha^2)(1+\alpha)(1-\alpha)$$
$$S(1-\alpha)=(1-\alpha^8)(1+\alpha^3)$$
$$S(1-\alpha)=(1-\alpha^3)(1+\alpha^3)$$
$$S(1-\alpha)=(1-\alpha^6)$$
$$S(1-\alpha)=(1-\alpha)$$
$$S=1$$